# Can I use HttpContext.Application instead of Session to store session specific data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, session-variables, session-state

I need to access user specific data in the controllers of an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. My controller class has 2 controller methods:

```
[ControllerSessionState(ControllerSessionState.ReadOnly)]
public class CalendarController : BasicController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ControllerMethod1()
    {
       //reads session specific data
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ControllerMethod1()
    {
       //stores session specific data
    }
}
```

I want the requests to be parallelized, that is, ControllerMethod1 should be able to run in parallel with ControllerMethod2. For this reason I marked the session as **ReadOnly**. However, ControllerMethod2 has to write data to the "session". As this is not allowed, I think about storing my data in HttpContext.Application. I could encode the user-id in the name of the object, for example:

```
 HttpContext.Application["Data" + currentUser.UserId] = <<my_data>>;
```

Can I do it this way? Does this approach have any disadvantages?

Comment: Yes, there's a disadvantage: This approach still doesn't address the concurrency issue and it adds the complexity of having to deal with the custom keys (`"Data" + currentUser.UserId`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify `ControllerSessionState.ReadOnly` for a controller that obviously needs to write in the session store.

Instead, try to address the concurrency issue another way (for example using an appropriate locking mechanism).

Also, think about what are the odds that the same user accesses both methods at exactly the same time. I think these odds are so low that concurrency is not worth thinking about in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For your information: I want to execute the controllers in parallel, because one controller is used to stop the execution of the second controller, if the user of the application does not want to wait any longer for the result.

Comment: How exactly does it stop the other controller?

Comment: The object that performs the long running operation is stored in the session (or in httpcontext.application). The stop-controller calls a particular method on this object in order to stop the operation. Unfortunately, it seems that sessionstate.readonly does not lead to concurrent requests, as I have expected (maybe this only works in ASP .NET MVC 3).